# Check if \" escape sequence at the start or end of a String php

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find out if I have a certain escape sequence at the start or the end of a line. If it is there then it's ok otherwise I need to put it at the start or end. I can't figure out how to do it. Please help

e.g. lets say I want this kind of string

`"\"Hello\""`

but I encounter a string like this

`Hello`

then I should change it into the required format which is

`"\"Hello\""`

Comment: Dont get your question, but this will work: `$str='Hello'; print '"'.addslashes('"'.$str.'"').'"';`

Comment: is there any way to check that if we have escape sequence at the start or end ??

Answer (score 0):

This regex:

```
 ^(?:\\")?(.*?)(?:\\")?$
```

allows to extract contents optionally surrounded by `\"` sequences. (Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vE2iN1/1). Then you can replace it with `\"$1\"`:

```
preg_replace('/^(?:\\\\")?(.*?)(?:\\\\")?$/', '\"$1\"', $str);
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/QCYxtP

Comment: Just one thing more. This regex will work perfectly if my string is surrounded in between these quotation marks `' '`. Is there to make it work for both this `' '` and `" "`.The reason I need this is to change some live data on clients request. and some of that data has quotation marks like this `" "` and some have like this `' '`